# Error triggering animation based on boolean value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Have a button that gets animated when a IsBusy boolean property on the ViewModel is True:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Grid.Row="4"
        Command="{Binding QuitCommand}" 
        Content="{x:Static r:Resources.Close}" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TestStoryboard}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger> **<-- here is line 167 position 27**
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

**Storyboard:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="TestStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="25"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="180"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

If I initialize the IsBusy property to false and then launch the animation later, then everything works.

If I initialize the IsBusy property to true then I get the following errors:

> '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path
>   '(0).(1)[2].(2)'. 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.' Line
>   number '167' and line position '27'.

**ViewModel:**

```
public const string IsBusyPropertyName = "IsBusy";

private bool _IsBusy = true;

public bool IsBusy
{
    get
    {
        return _IsBusy;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_IsBusy == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        RaisePropertyChanging(IsBusyPropertyName);
        _IsBusy = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(IsBusyPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Timing issue?

Comment: what about the `TestStoryboard`, the problem might be there.

Comment: @KingKing - Well the storyboard does work, just not if I set IsBusy to true from the start.  I posted it so you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
 <Button.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform/>
        <SkewTransform/>
        <RotateTransform/>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Button.RenderTransform>
```

before

```
    <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TestStoryboard}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger> **<-- here is line 167 position 27**
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

If it's already true then it calls storyboard before RenderTransform is set, I believe.